# Rails view Helper function and the link_to function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a helper function (eg in `application_helper.rb`) that generates a `link_to` based on parameters passed in to the helper function. If I were putting the link in an ERB file it would be of the format:

```
<%= link_to 'Some Text', { :controller => 'a_controller', :action => 'an_action' } %>
```

In the helper function, the Text, Controller and Action are all passed in or calculated. The code in the helper function is:

```
params = "{ :controller => '#{controller}', :action => '#{action_to_take}'}"
html   = "#{link_to some_text, params }<p />"
return html
```

The link that is generated has the correct text, however the parameters are literally the contents of the `params` string.

How can I get the `params` string to be evaluated (as it is in an ERB file)?

Comment: Where is the params string coming from that you want to evaluate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you have things overcomplicated in your head. Unless you're trying to do something very odd (and inadvisable) this would work:

```
def link_helper text, controller, action
  link_to text, :controller => controller, :action => action
end
```

Although, as you can see it's not worth making it a helper - it's barely any more simple than the functionality it's wrapping, and much less flexible.

The link_to helper returns a string, so it's very simple to use in the way you want:

```
def link_helper text
  # some helper logic:
  controller = @controller || "pages"
  action     = @action     || "index"

  # create the html string:
  html = "A link to the #{controller}##{action} action:"
  html << link_to(text, :controller => controller, :action => action)
  html # ruby does not require explicit returns
end
```

Comment: Thanks. That works if all I needed to do was to return the link_to but I edited the method down to post. The link_to is the last part of a bigger piece of HTML that the helper creates, which is why I was appending it to the HTML variable. Also the values of controller and action vary depending on other logic in the helper.

Comment: OKay, I've updated with an example of what it sounds like you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could simple use url_for helper .

link_to "Some Text", url_for(:action=> :action_name , :controller=> :controller_name )

Comment: You certainly could do this but it would be pointless - link_to calls url_for internally so this functionality is identical to `link_to "Some Text", :action=> :action_name , :controller=> :controller_name`